# How long can you stay in the UK if you are supported by non-family UK citizen?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I want to invite my former nanny (Brazilian) to the UK to stay with me and my family for a period of time. She will come as my guest and stay with me and I will support her. She only has about £2,000 in savings which is what she received from me when I had to dismiss her when I left the country. Will immigration believe she is here as a guest and not going to work for me. Would she be better applying for a visa for a short amount of time?

Comment: If I were an ECO I would find it hard to believe she is coming to stay with you merely as a visitor, particularly when its clear she is not of considerable financial means. That's a red flag

Answer (score 13):

You want your former nanny to come to the UK using the Standard Visitor Visa as the vehicle for getting her in. You will sponsor the application. **This is a very bad idea.**

There were lots of people doing this: domestic workers were brought in by their sponsor, their passports were confiscated, they lived in [slave-like conditions](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/607256/ODWS-victims-of-slavery-hum-traff-v4.pdf) and overstayed their visitor visas because they were unable to leave their employer's household. A lot of women ended up in hospitals or safe houses for domestic violence. The violence and exploitation that these people were subjected to created a [public outcry](http://www.parliament.uk/business/publications/written-questions-answers-statements/written-statement/Commons/2016-03-07/HCWS583/).

Parliament finally got involved and passed the [Modern Slavery Act 2015](http://services.parliament.uk/bills/2014-15/modernslavery.html).

The result is that the importing of domestic workers via the visitor programme is one of the UK's "*hot buttons*". They are on the alert for it and once the ECO (or IO) sees what's going on, they will refuse the application full stop. And since it's a '*hot button*' they may send an inspector around to see if you have any other undocumented workers in your household. And finally, your [credibility as a sponsor](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/uk_politics/1924881.stm) will be shot to hell and hence it's a bad idea.

Your nanny is Brazilian and can get in without a visa. In that case when you are finally caught they will throw in a [harbouring charge](http://www.cps.gov.uk/legal/h_to_k/immigration/) in addition to the standard GBP 10k per person fine for employing an illegal.

If you want to do things legally, your nanny can use the [Overseas Domestic Worker Programme](https://www.gov.uk/domestic-workers-in-a-private-household-visa/overview). This is a *[closely managed](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/602790/Domestic-workers-in-private-households-v17_0ext.pdf)* inward route that nannies can benefit from (if you and she can jump through all the hurdles).  I know it's a pain, but otherwise you are doing things illegally.

---

For your specific questions...

> How long can you stay in the UK if you are supported by non-family UK
>   citizen?

Following the rules laid down in [Appendix V](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules), a visitor can stay up to 6 months.

> Will immigration believe she is here as a guest and not going to work
>   for me.

In all likelihood, no they will not. It is not the historical pattern of domestic servants entering the UK as visitors to actually engage as tourists. Instead they are put to work by their employers and overstay their visas and this is accompanied by violence and exploitation. While in some cases the intent to visit may be genuine, the authorities have to observe the known pattern.

> Would she be better applying for a visa for a short amount of time?

No. Even if she applies for a visa of one day, or even one minute, you cannot escape the pattern that you are attempting to import a domestic for the purposes of abuse and exploitation. As mentioned above, it is a "**hot button**".

---

Having said all of that, this site's remit is about travel. You can ask further questions about bringing your nanny to the UK in our sister site, [Expats](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions). They are a great resource for questions such as yours.

Comment: Suppose it's a legitimate social visit. The kids miss their dear nanny, and the parents want to bring her in for a visit. Is there any way for the visitor to enter the UK in the face of the sensitivity about abusive labor practices?

Comment: @phoog they have to go on the generic pattern, and history tells us that the 'dear nanny' will eventually end up in a safe house for domestic violence. You wouldn't want that, would you?  You can read my briefing at http://www.ilpa.org.uk/data/resources/30835/15.03.25-ILPA-for-House-of-Lords-Ping-Pong-Modern-Slavery-Bill.pdf  and also the Chief's report at http://icinspector.independent.gov.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Potential-Victims-of-Modern-Slavery-_Inspection-report.pdf and try to get your head around the words: "Hot Button" :)

Comment: I'm asking from the perspective of the sponsor.  Is there no way to get this woman i to the country for a visit?  If she is a genuine visitor then wouldn't it be illegal to use the overseas domestic worker program? Anyway it seems that program is off the table here because the sponsor must be a "British or European Economic Area (EEA) national who usually lives outside the UK and who doesn’t intend to remain in the UK for more than six months"

Comment: @phoog you are invited (as always) to put that question to the community here (or Expats). It is a more generic question than the OP's, and would not (IMHO) be a duplicate.  I suggest voting up/down/sideways on this question and then framing up a canonical question using community procedures. It would make a great one given the legislation and current public mood about abuse and exploitation.

Comment: Thanks @phoog I was intending it to be a legitimate social visit rather than an opportunity to exploit her. She is really keen to come and I would like to give her that opportunity.

Comment: @GayotFow I can see how my intentions might be interpreted by an immigration officer and understand how the UK is quite rightly trying to crack down on exploitation. Had never imagined it would be so difficult.

Comment: @H.Hodgson, If the children just miss her, I suppose she could visit them for a few days, but I believe she would need to travel by herself the rest of the time. Immigration officials are going to want to see her travel plans, reservations, tour/cruise tickets for people her age, and probably way more than $2,000 in her accounts (completely independent of you). On arrival, it's even possible they'll go through her luggage, her emails, and her phone, to see if things are consistent with her story.

Comment: For reference of thinks immigration authorities want to avoid (story's about US but I imagine this can be located just as well in Europe): https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2017/06/lolas-story/524490/